# TextBox OnTextChanged / PostBack not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

My problem is that I can't seem to get my textbox to fire the `OnTextChanged` event.  I also checked and it doesn't seem like it is doing an `autopostback` despite the fact that it is set to true.

Basically, I am trying to validate the text in the textbox and either enable or disable a button based on the validation status.

Here's my code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="panelAccessControl" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <asp:Panel ID="panelAddMileageRate" runat="server" BorderWidth="2" >
        <h2>Add Mileage Rate</h2>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManagerMileageRate" runat="server" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelAddMileageRate" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <p>
                    Purpose:
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAddPurpose" runat="server"
                         AutoPostBack="true" Width="200px"></asp:DropDownList>
                    <br />
                    Country:
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAddCountry" runat="server"
                         AutoPostBack="true" Width="200px" >
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <br />
                    Effective Date:
                    <asp:Calendar ID="calAddEffectiveDate" runat="server"> 
                    </asp:Calendar>
                    <br />
                    Mileage Rate:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddMileageRate" runat="server"
                        AutoPostBack="true" Width="200px" 
                        CausesValidation="true" 
                        ontextchanged="txtAddMileageRate_TextChanged">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
                         ID="validatorAddMileageRate"
                         ControlToValidate="txtAddMileageRate" runat="server" 
                         SetFocusOnError="true"
                         ErrorMessage="Only Numbers allowed" 
                         ValidationExpression="^\d{1,20}(\.\d{0,4})?$">
                    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                </p>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <p>
            <asp:Button ID="buttonAddSecurityGroup" runat="server" 
                        Text="Submit" onclick="buttonAddSecurityGroup_Click" />
        </p>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</asp:Panel>
```

The text box in question is `txtAddMileageRate`.

Comment: That didn't make it work, still no postback or event firing.

Comment: refer "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341080/asp-net-dropdownlist-autopostback-not-working-what-am-i-missing"

Comment: Change your UpdatePanel to   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelAddMileageRate" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" >

Comment: @kumarch1 it kind of worked.  When the textbox text is valid, the event triggers and postback works.  Unfortunately, when the text is invalid, it does not trigger the event or postback?  Any thoughts?

Comment: what do you mean by text is invalid ?

Comment: based on the RegularExpressionValidator.  If the RegularExpressionValidator that is linked to the textbox is not valid per the regex, it does not postback.  If the text is valid per the regex, it does the postback as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67134/discussion-between-kumarch1-and-kevin).

Answer (score 0):

Set the `EventName` property for your `txtAddMileageRate` `AsyncPostBackTrigger` to `TextChanged`.

Add following codes inside your update panel and outside of `ContentTemplate`

```
<Triggers>             
  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtAddMileageRate" 
                          EventName="TextChanged" />            
</Triggers>
```

Other sugguestion:

Have you tried looking at the AutoComplete (http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/autocomplete/autocomplete) control that is part of the AjaxControlToolKit? Its behaves the same way you want your solution to behave.

Comment: it still does the same thing as I commented above.  The postback / trigger works when the textbox text is valid per the RegularExpressionValidator, but when the text in invalid, it does not fire the trigger or postback.